# BDD/TDD: can dependencies be a behavior?

Tags: tdd, bdd

I've been told not to use implementation details. A dependency seems like an implementation detail. However I could phrase it also as a behavior.

Example: A LinkList depends on a storage engine to store its links (eg LinkStorageInterface). The constructor needs to be passed an instance of an implemented LinkStorageInterface to do its job.
I can't say 'shouldUseLinkStorage'. But maybe I can say 'shouldStoreLinksInStorage'.

What is correct to 'test' in this case? Should I test that it stores links in a store (behavior) or don't test this at all?

Comment: Are you asking about test titles or how to write your tests?

Comment: It seems that you are getting far to deeply into navel gazing, aka "meta". I would recommend going back to some basic Agile principles such as "do the simplest thing that could possibly work," and ask yourself why you need to separate the link storage mechanism from the LinkedList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency itself is not an expected behavior, but the actions called on the dependency most certainly are. You should test the stuff you (the caller) know about, and avoid testing the stuff that requires you to have intimate knowledge of the inner workings of the SUT.

Expanding your example a little, lets imagine that our LinkStorageInterface has the following definition (Pseudo-Code):

```
Interface LinkStorageInterface

  void WriteListToPersistentMedium(LinkList list)

End Interface
```

Now, since you (the caller) are providing the concrete implementation for that interface it is perfectly reasonable for you to test that `WriteListToPersistentMedium()` gets called when you invoke the `Save()` method on your `LinkList`.

A test might look like this, again using pseudo-code:

```
void ShouldSaveLinkListToPersistentMedium()

  define da = new MockLinkListStorage()  
  define list = new LinkList(da)

  list.Save()

  Assert.Method(da.WriteListToPersistentMedium).WasCalledWith(list)

end method
```

You have tested expected behavior without testing implementation specific details of either your SUT, or your mock. What you want to avoid testing (mostly) are things like:

1. Order in which methods were called
2. Making a method, or property public just so you can check it
3. Anything that does not directly involve the expected behavior you are testing

Again, a dependency is something that you as the consumer of the class are providing, so you expect it to be used. Otherwise there is no point in having that dependency in the first place.

Comment: @Josh Would you say that testing void methods that have some behaviour is good practice? e.g by calling Verify on a Mock? As there is nothing returned in the method.

Comment: @User101 - Yes. It's the difference between interaction based testing and state based testing. Regardless of the return type of the method, you might still want to test some interaction it has with a dependency. The dependency can be a mock... you don't really care. What is important is how your code responds to various, controllable behaviors or the dependency. "What happens if it returns null?" "What happens if it throws an exception?" etc...

Comment: @Josh thanks that makes sense for behaviours, what if the class is mapping one dto to another dto and then calling an external interface with the new dto, the overall method still returns a void. Is this worth testing that the mapping occured correctly by verifying that the mocked interface gets called once with the new dto?

Answer (score 1):

LinkStorageInterface is not an implementation detail - its name suggests an interface to to an engine. In which case the name *shouldUseLinkStorage* has more value than *shouldStoreLinksInStorage*.

That's my 2 pennies worth!